# GraphQL and ACL

Tags: graphql, apollo

We are investigating how we could introduce GraphQL and we are now studying how to use GraphQL with our ACL system.

We basically have this model (as an example):

```
interface Foo {
  title: string;
}
```

if you have, lets say, *Editing Permissions*, then your post model becomes:

```
interface Foo {
  title: string;
  bar: string;
  foobar: string; 
}
```

basically, your `Foo` object is delivered with different fields accordingly with your permissions.

---

We have been doing some research and a couple of options came out (such as having different types per acl, etc.). But we are not sure what's the best way to do it is.

#### How should we be describing our types?

Comment: You should give a try to https://github.com/maticzav/graphql-shield and see if that fits your case or you may need to roll out your one custom directived around permissions. You can find a working example of the latter here: https://github.com/ecerroni/apollo-connector-kit/blob/master/backend/src/config/_roles-permissions.js

Comment: Maybe my answer here could be a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49147693/graphql-how-to-distinguish-public-from-private-fields/49152787#49152787